# What's the best way to get the last N elements of a Perl array?

Tags: perl, arrays, slice

What's the best way to get the last N elements of a Perl array?

If the array has less than N, I don't want a bunch of `undefs` in the return value.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
@last_n = @source[-$n..-1];
```

If you require no `undef`s, then:

```
@last_n = ($n >= @source) ? @source : @source[-$n..-1];
```

Comment: It work okay.  undefs go into @last_n in the positions for which @source has no values, which is correct for some not-entirely-unreasonable semantics of what it means to "take the last N elements".

Comment: @Schwern: I'm intrigued to know what surprised you. Is it the arithmetic with negative integers?  Hopefully the conditional expression is obvious.

Comment: @Borodin It's been nine years, but I'm going to guess that because `3..1` doesn't work hadn't considered `-3..-1`.

Comment: @Schwern: Hah, that's what I guessed, and it seems that at least four people agree with you. But nine years? Not since writing Perl certainly, and probably not since doing integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want is called a [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

Answer (score 4):

```
@a = (a .. z);
@last_five = @a[ $#a - 4 .. $#a ];
say join " ", @last_five;
```

outputs:

> v w x y z

Answer (score 1):

simple, no math:

```
@a = reverse @a;
@a = splice(@a, 0, $elements_to_keep);
@a = reverse @a;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @a in scalar context gives the length on an array a and because `@a == $#a + 1` (unless `$[` is set to non-zero), one can get the slice from the $nth (counting from zero) to to last element by `@a[$n..@a-1]` -- #tmtowtdi.

Answer (score -1):

TMTOWTDI, but I think this is a bit easier to read (but removes the elements from `@source`):

```
my @last_n = splice(@source, -$n);
```

And if you are not sure that `@source` has at least `$n` elements:

```
my @last_n = ($n >= @source) ? @source : splice(@source, -$n);
```

Comment: That *removes* the elements from the original array. An array slice leaves them in place, which is most likely what is wanted.